# How to append current window location in the href value of anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to share the current window url for the social links as showm below. In my cshtml I have the below code, where I am trying to replace [CurrentWindowLocation] with the current page URL using javascript function window.location.href, but unable to do that.

```
@using System.Web
@{
    var shareWord = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ViewData["shareWord"] as string ?? string.Empty);
}

 <a href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=Companytext=@(shareWord)[CurrentWindowLocation]#tagCompany" >
      <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
 </a>

<a href="//www.facebook.com/share.php?u=[CurrentWindowLocation]" >
      <i class="icon-fb"></i>
</a>
```

I tried below code but could not get the correct result

```
<a href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=Companytext=@(shareWord)" + $(window.location.href)+ "#tagCompany" >
      <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
 </a>
```

My expectation in the href is `//twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=Companytext=ShareWordhttp://www.mycompany.com#tagCompany`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a class="twitter-share-link" href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=Companytext=@(shareWord)LOCATION_HREF#tagCompany" >
  <i class="icon-twitter">link</i>
</a>
<script>
  (function(){
    var link = document.getElementsByClassName('twitter-share-link')[0]
    link.setAttribute('href', link.getAttribute('href').replace('LOCATION_HREF',location.href))
  })()
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you.. this solution helped to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try use context from server side instead of jquery

```
<a href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=Companytext=@(shareWord)@(Context.Request.Host)@(Context.Request.Path)#tagCompany" >
     <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
</a>
```

---

hope it useful!

Chu Nguyen

Comment: Thanks Chu Nguyen for your response. I cannot use this option because this application has no domain configured in IIS. It is accessed from a different application through redirection/rewrite rules. So, request.host returns me localhost. This is the main reason i am trying through jquery or javascript.